# Why is this C code buggy?

Tags: c, file-io, while-loop, feof

On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586423/why-is-this-ocaml-program-faster-than-my-c-program), [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin) pointed out the following:

> It's (probably) not really related to your question, but `while (!feof(fileptr)){` is pretty much a guaranteed bug.

I figured I would start a separate question since that comment is somewhat off-topic.  Could someone explain this to me?  This was the first program I've written in straight C before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this statement is that `feof` is still (initially) false when the end of the file has been reached -- it only becomes true after the first failed attempt to read past the end of the file.

Hence

```
char mychar;
while(!feof(fileptr))
{
    fread(&mychar, sizeof(char), 1, fileptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "The char is '%c'.\n", mychar);
}
```

will process one char too many.

The correct way is to check the return value of `fread` (or whatever function you're using to read) or, alternatively, to call `feof` *after* the function that does the reading. For example:

```
char mychar;
while(fread(&mychar, sizeof(char), 1, fileptr) > 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "The char is '%c'.\n", mychar);
```

Comment: nit: the problem is not that the loop reads one char too many, but that it writes one too many.

Comment: The devil is in the details... I guess that's why we're programmers. ;) Edited to "process one char too many", since that's also a good description of what would happen in a real application.

Answer (score 5):

Google finds this: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

It says "The author has yet to see any student use the feof() function correctly!"

To summarize, the C file functions like `fread` and `fwrite` return status values anyway which you **<blink>should not ignore</blink>**. Checking the value of `feof` is one of those bolting the stable door after the horse has already fled kind of things.

Comment: Give a short synopsis of the link in your answer. It makes your answer much more valuable to a search engine.

Comment: By some incredible coincidence, I was in the process of doing exactly that when I received your commented communication.

Comment: @Kinopiko - Alliteration is awesome.

Comment: This is now the top hit on Google for "bolting the stable door after the horse has already fled", which isn't bad for something posted 18 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

The C FAQ list has an [answer](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html) along with answers to many other such frequently asked questions:

> In C, end-of-file is only indicated after an input routine has tried to read, and failed.