# Putting strings into a 2D chararray in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

How do I put strings into an 2D char array from (for example) a file?

```
char buffert[10][30];
int i = 0;

while(!feof(somefile)) {
  fscanf(somefile, "%s", temp);
  buffert[i][] = temp;
  i++;
}
```

This will not do it.

Comment: Also see this note on using feof like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588336/why-is-this-c-code-buggy

Comment: Or, see this explanation in the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do away with the temp, and drop each string straight into the space you created for it (in buffert in this case).

```
char buffert[10][30];
int i = 0;
FILE * fp = fopen("myfile", "r");
while(!feof(fp)) { 
  fscanf(fp, "%s", buffert[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Here the file pointer is called fp.  You will have to make a bunch of checks to prevent overflowing the 10 entries available in buffert, or the 30 chars available in each of its strings.  You should also avoid feof().

Comment: This has two problems: An overlong long string, or too many strings, will both overflow `buffert`; and when end-of-file is reached, `i` will be incremented one too many times, because the return value of `fscanf` isn't tested.

Comment: I agree, which is why I provide a caveat about checks. However, I want to supply the simplest variation that demonstrates the point that the OP needs. It's a pedagogical thing.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Ouch! My point wasn't about feof() at all. Do I have to nit-pick the OP's question to avoid getting stung?

Comment: @Ewan Todd: The `feof` bug is not trivial and pointing it out is not nitpicking. Of course, you could fix your answer instead of helping perpetuate buggy code in which case my downvote would be reversed.

Comment: @Ewan Todd, I don't think it's about avoiding `feof()`, I think it's about using it correctly.

Comment: If the OP is trying to cut down a tree whilst standing on a wheely chair balanced precariously on the roof of a car without the handbrake applied, and is having trouble starting the chainsaw - the best response isn't to just start the chainsaw for him and continue on your way.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
while(i < 10 && fscanf(somefile, "%29s%*[^ \t\n]", buffer[i]) != EOF) {
  i++;
}
```

The `"%29s"` format specifier reads up to 29 characters into `buffer[i]`, which is all it has space for.  The `"%*[^ \t\n]"` reads and throws away non-whitespace, in case the string was longer than 29 characters.

Additionally, `while (!feof()) { }` is almost always the wrong thing to do, because `EOF` isn't set on the stream until end of file is encountered.

Comment: Ok, great answer I will check on this more advanced stuff with built-in check later.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=971224):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int dirsize = 80;
  char array[9][dirsize];
  int linenum = 0;
  FILE *filepointer;
  filepointer = fopen("projectfile.txt","r");
  while (feof(filepointer) == 0)
  {
    linenum++;
    fgets(array[linenum], dirsize, filepointer);
  }
  fclose(filepointer);
}
```

Another solution with a pointer to arrays instead of array of arrays [is here.](http://brijraj.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!F3F32C257587DCC6!365.entry)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look to me like you're actually COPYING the string into an array. I'm surprised it compiles. am I missing something?

look into strcpy or strncpy, or you can copy using for loops.